# How to modify SQL entries en masse?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have 15 million records with poorly formatted date entries. They look like this: "Thu Jun 09 08:00:01 UTC 2011" (for example). This is on a Microsoft SQL server.

In excel, I broke up (some of) the data like this:

"Wed Jul 27 06:14:58 UTC 2011"
--> separate cells =    Wed | Jul | 27 | 06:14:58 | 2011 |

This was a rough-but-workable way to cut up the data in a small sample. Now I need to do something similar in the SQL database as a whole.

I'm a new user of SQL, but I need a way to turn this into usable data. What would be the best way to change the date data into a well-organized format? Thanks!

EDIT1: The data is saved as a string. I inherited the database and am trying to learn all I can to make it useful (hence currently learning SQL, newbie, etc.). The ideal situation would be to convert the data to a single properly formatted date/time, but more rough cut solutions will also work for my purposes. Really anything that gets the data out of a string format and into a form I can sort by date.

EDIT2: I would use the data in excel (where I am capable of translating it into properly formatted date), but there are too many entries to pull them all in.  The original data is in SQL, which is why I'm trying to get my head around how to solve this (probably very simple) problem.

EDIT3: Thanks for the suggestions and help. I'm very new at this.

Comment: Is the column that these datesa are stored in a DATETIME data type, or just a text column that some fool inserted the date into as a UTC string?

Comment: Are they stored in the database as dates?  Or strings?  If strings, why?

Comment: if its a datetime column, you can just use date functions to operate on it and get the specific info that you're chasing

Comment: Are your records string-formatted like that, or is it just that the default date format looks like that?  Because splitting it out into part-columns makes it FAR less usable.

Answer (score 1):

From your data in Excel sheet import the data into sql server in separate columns and you will end up with something like ...

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ([Day] VarChar(5),[Month] VarChar(3)
                                  , [Date] INT, [Time] VarChar(9), [Year] INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('Wed' ,'Jul' ,27 ,'06:14:58' ,2011 )
```

Then you the following query to get a proper DateTime format and cast the it to a datetime value and update the table to have a column with datetime data type.

```
SELECT *, 
      CAST(
      CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))
      + CASE [Month]   WHEN 'Jan' THEN '01'
                       WHEN 'Feb' THEN '02'
                       WHEN 'Mar' THEN '03'
                       WHEN 'Apr' THEN '04'
                       WHEN 'May' THEN '05'
                       WHEN 'Jun' THEN '06'
                       WHEN 'Jul' THEN '07'
                       WHEN 'Aug' THEN '08'
                       WHEN 'Sep' THEN '09'
                       WHEN 'Oct' THEN '10'
                       WHEN 'Nov' THEN '11'
                       WHEN 'Dec' THEN '12'
      END 
     + CAST([Date] AS VARCHAR(2)) 
     + ' '
     + [Time]   AS DATETIME) AS DateAsDateTime      

FROM @Table
```

### Result

```
╔═════╦═══════╦══════╦══════════╦══════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ Day ║ Month ║ Date ║   Time   ║ Year ║     DateAsDateTime      ║
╠═════╬═══════╬══════╬══════════╬══════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ Wed ║ Jul   ║   27 ║ 06:14:58 ║ 2011 ║ 2011-07-27 06:14:58.000 ║
╚═════╩═══════╩══════╩══════════╩══════╩═════════════════════════╝
```